# Bind label with two different values-javafx

Tags: java, javafx, label

I have a live `javafx` user application which has a label : `No of answers/No of questions` ,
No of answers increases as the user answers the question, and number of questions increases as one class throws questions to user.

Label initially looks like -  `0/0`

I want to bind two different variables `(NumberOfAnswers, NumberOfQuestions)` to this label, say if I have 10 questions thrown to user and user has answered 2 it should look like : `2/10`

```
Label ansQuestLbl = new Label("0/0");
    if (answerConnector!= null) {
        log.info("Going to bind , No of answers: "+answerConnector.getNoOfAnswers());
        ansQuesLbl.textProperty().bind(answerConnector.getNoOfAnswers().asString());
        log.info("Bound number of answers with label on UI");
    }
```

This only binds Number of answers to the label.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the return type of `getNoOfAnswers()`?

Comment: SimpleIntegerProperty

Comment: How does the setter for `setNoOfAnsers` look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is [`Bindings.concat(Object... args)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#concat-java.lang.Object...-):

For example:

```
IntegerProperty noOfAnswers = answerConnector.noOfAnswersProperty();
IntegerProperty noOfQuestions = answerConnector.noOfQuestionsProperty();
ansQuesLbl.textProperty().bind(Bindings.concat(noOfAnswers, "/", noOfQuestions));
```

Or:

```
IntegerProperty noOfAnswers = answerConnector.noOfAnswersProperty();
IntegerProperty noOfQuestions = answerConnector.noOfQuestionsProperty();
ansQuesLbl.textProperty().bind(noOfAnswers.asString().concat("/").concat(noOfQuestions.asString()));
```

---

Note: To avoid problems with the Properties I would recommand to follow the javafx naming convention, so that the class for `answerConnector` should look like this:

```
public class AnswerConnector {
    private final IntegerProperty noOfAnswers = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

    public IntegerProperty noOfAnswersProperty() {
        return noOfAnswers;
    }

    public int getNoOfAnswers() {
        return noOfAnswers.get();
    }

    public void setNoOfAnswers(int noOfAnswers) {
        this.noOfAnswers.set(noOfAnswers);
    }

    // same for noOfQuestions
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, for more elaborate formatting you can use [`Bindings.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-).

Comment: I am trying to it on my javafx scene, Do I need to refresh my scene because it is getting bound with label but not updated on my UI ?

Comment: What do you mean with _not updated on my UI_? Where can the values of `noOfAnswers` and `noOfQuestion` be changed? By the way better rename `getNoOfAnsers` to `noOfAnsersProperty`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, It is not getting updated on `javafx scene` , as the value of answers changing ,label value is not getting updated on scene/UI.

Comment: Is it possible that you accidentally change the object of `answerConnector` or `getNoOfAnswers` and not the value of the properties?

Comment: No i am updating the value only, while debugging value is getting updated also, but not on UI, may be i need to refresh my page or do the bind in separate thread?

Comment: setter is setting it correct as the value is getting updated, only not getting updated on label

Comment: Does your setter for `setNoOfAnsers` look like the one in my answer?

Comment: Able to do it now, was doing one mistake, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

[`Bindings.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) can be used for this purpose:

```
ansQuesLbl.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("%d/%d",
                                               answerConnector.noOfAnswersProperty(),
                                               answerConnector.noOfQuestionsProperty()));
```